# Mean of List of Coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, averages

Imagine I have the following list

```
l = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}
```

I want to take the mean only regarding the second element. That is, I want to find the coordinates of the points corresponding to

```
{{1, 2.5}, {2, 3}}
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this? In other words, how can I easily compute the mean points (in red) from a list of coordinates

[image]

**My approach:** `Mean /@ Split[Sort@l, Last[#2] >= Last[#1] &]`. Could this be improved?

Comment: `Mean /@ GatherBy[alist, First]` ? (where `alist` is the list in the OP. `l` is hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
alist = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}
```

then

```
groupedMeans = GroupBy[alist, First -> Last, Mean]
```

gives

`<|1 -> 5/2, 2 -> 3|>`

To recover the data as coordinates, you could do this:

```
KeyValueMap[List, groupedMeans]
```

`{{1, 5/2}, {2, 3}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}};
```

Using `Merge` and `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
Merge[Mean] @ MapApply[Rule] @ list
```

> <|1 -> 5/2, 2 -> 3|>

Using `SplitBy` (`list` is sorted by its first elements)

```
Mean /@ SplitBy[list, First]
```

> {{1, 5/2}, {2, 3}}

Answer (score 2):

As `Mean[x,x,x,...]` is x you can use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html), e.g.

```
Values[GroupBy[l, First, Mean]]
```

which yields: {{1, 5/2}, {2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}};
```

---

Using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
groupedMeans = Merge[Mean]@Join[Reap[Sow[Rule @@ #, #[[1]]] & /@ list][[2]]]
```

> `<|1 -> 5/2, 2 -> 3|>`

To retrieve the data as coordinates, you can proceed as @lericr did:

```
KeyValueMap[List, groupedMeans]
```

> `{{1, 5/2}, {2, 3}}`